# hibernate update always null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

iam new in hibernate, i have a entity class named student, it have 5 field, name, age, address, phone, and sex.
then i want to update name and age field.

```
student.setName("foo");
student.setAge("11");
getHibernateTemplate().update(student);
```

after i ran the code, the other field value become null, except the two field in the code above. i expecting my other field to stay as it is.

any suggest is deeply appreciated

btw sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating value first of all you have to get the value by primary key and then update the object(Bean) then update method should be called.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is retrieve your student from database before, to have a value for all the fields :

```
Student student = getHibernateTemplate().get(Student.class, id);
student.setName("foo");
student.setAge("11");
getHibernateTemplate().update(student);
```

Or, alternatively, you can do a manual update of your fields :

```
Session session;
boolean newSession=false;
try {
    session=getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
} catch (final HibernateException e) {
    session=getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    newSession=true;
}

session.createQuery(
  "update Student student set " +
  "student.Name = :studentName, " +
  "student.Age = :studentAge " +
  "where student.Id = :studentId")
.setString("studentName", "foo")
.setString("studentAge", "11")
.setString("studentId", id)
.executeUpdate();

if (newSession)
    session.close();
```

Comment: I think your alternate way is not appropriate since you are not using POJO for the hibernate.